# Is there the elliptictheta function in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I need the [EllipticTheta](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html) function in mathematica, I don't know if there is a corresponding function in numpy. Especially the second kind of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+elliptic+theta

mpmath has the jacobi theta functions:

http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/functions/elliptic.html#jacobi-theta-functions

If you want a vectorized function, you can write

```
import mpmath
import numpy as np

jtheta = np.vectorize(mpmath.jtheta, 'D')

print(jtheta(1,2,1j*np.linspace(0,0.9,15)))
```

Note that `np.vectorize` does not speed it up --- it just allows 
it to work directly on array inputs. mpmath functions work with
arb. precision floats, so they can sometimes be slower than equivalent
functions implemented in machine-precision fp.

Comment: Thanks, I've only looked into numpy. I didn't know this package at that time.